GDAL with ECW support on Windows
I have an 84GB ECW image I'm trying to split into tiles. Can anyone help me figure out how to install the ECW plug in from Hexagon for Windows (https://supportsi.hexagon.com/help/s/article/ERDAS-ECW-JP2-SDK-Read-Only-Redistributable-download)? I'm not a coder nor do I have experience with GIS so I'm having a hard time understanding directions that I'm finding online (like here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW).
I've already downloaded the read only license from Hexagon but what is the next step?

Do you want to save the tiles also as ECW, or is the aim to read ECW and write into some open format like TIFF?

TIFF would be great!

It's been a very long time since I've had to deal with ECWs, but assuming you have downloaded and installed the free read-only ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK v5.5 from Hexagon, you should just be able to download and use a version of GDAL that includes ECW support from the GISInternals site.

Thank you! I just installed a version with ECW support. Now how can I split my image into tiles? Not sure where to go from here.

Installation packages from gisinternals and from OSGeo4W contain all that is needed for reading ECW. If write support is needed then the GDAL user must acquire the license and the SDK from Hexagon and compile GDAL by themselves.

Yes, then I need to compile GDAL on my own. Thoughts on how to do this?

That may be complicated on Windows, but if you have enough money for the ECW license then you can certainly also hire some experienced GDAL developer to make a special build for you.

"Now how can I split my image into tiles? Not sure where to go from here" - Ask a new question.  "Yes, then I need to compile GDAL on my own." No you don't. Once you have installed the free read-only ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK v5.5 from Hexagon and also installed GDAL from GISInternals or GDAL+ ECW Plugin from OSGeo4W then you have everything you need.

A GDAL Windows version that has a read-only support for the ECW format can be installed from the https://gisinternals.com site, or by using the OSGeo4W installer https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/. At least the development versions from page https://gisinternals.com/development.php come with the ECW driver
The ECW driver may not belong to the default OSGeoW4 installation but it can be selected when using the Advanced install.

It is possible to check with gdalinfo if GDAL has the driver
gdalinfo --format ECW
Format Details:
  Short Name: ECW
  Long Name: ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.5)
  Supports: Raster
  Extension: ecw
  Help Topic: drivers/raster/ecw.html
...


That window is for OSGeo4W. I edited my answer for making it more clear.

Thank you--this worked! However, it seems like this installer can't translate ecw files so I believe I need to compile GDAL on my own and use a license from Hexagon. Do you know how to do that by any chance?

Do you mean that something like gdal_translate input.ecw output.tif does not work? What is the error? Or do you need for some special reason to write ECW?

The error is: "Input file size is 41971, 37148
ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `valencia.tif' failed: Permission denied"
I was trying to use translate because gdal2tiles was also giving me an error: "RuntimeError: OGR Error: General Error"

Permission denied has probably nothing to do with the ECW driver but something else.  Take care to write into a directory where you have write rights and try this gdal_translate -of GeoTIFF -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -srcwin 0 0 1000 1000 input.ecw tile.tif. It cuts a 1000x1000 pixel sized area from the top-left corner.

This converted my image to tif but didn't create tiles. When I try to use gdal2tiles on the generated tif file I get:
"...
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py", line 2220, in open_input
if (self.in_srs.ExportToProj4() != self.out_srs.ExportToProj4()) or (
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo\osr.py", line 969, in ExportToProj4
return _osr.SpatialReference_ExportToProj4(self, *args)
RuntimeError: OGR Error: General Error"

Oh I see, it created a single tile. Thats great! Now I just need to create tiles for the whole image. Can I do this using using gdal_translate?

Gdal_translate is made to create one output. You can script it and pass a different -srcwin each time but probably that is not the optimal solution for tiling. Gdal2tiles is made to make tiles and if the features that it has suit you it should be a better option. I cannot say what is wrong with your installation.

Ok great-- thank you for all your help! Really appreciate it.
